# REST API access from Zepp OS app example request

Tags: javascript, zeppos

I try to develop Amazfit watch app for Zepp OS (here are [dev docs](https://docs.zepp.com/)).

I need to get some data from REST API service. [There is](https://docs.zepp.com/docs/guides/framework/side-service/intro/) mentioned [Fetch API](https://docs.zepp.com/docs/reference/side-service-api/fetch/) should be used.

*Could you advice some working example?*

Comment: the fetch api reference redirects to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: there are many examples on how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch of course these are generic javascript implementations, not specific to the Zepp OS